# How to add confirmation message before deleting?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, crud

I am trying to add a confirmation message before deleting a data in my table. But I don't know how and where to put the code. I tried look up other codes but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
        <?php $a = 0?>

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 

            echo "<tr id=".$a++.">
                <th scope='row' class='row-data'>".$row['user_id']."</th>
                <td class='row-data'>".$row['full_name']."</td>
                <td class='row-data'>".$row['user_name']."</td>
                <td><input type='button' 
                    value='EDIT'
                           onclick='editUser()'' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' 
                    value='DELETE' 
                      onclick='deleteUser()' /></td>
            </tr>
        
        </tbody>";
       }; ?>
 

        function deleteUser() {
            var rowId = 
                event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
          //this gives id of tr whose button was clicked
            var data = 
            document.getElementById(rowId).querySelectorAll(".row-data"); 
          /*returns array of all elements with 
          "row-data" class within the row with given id*/

            var uID = data[0].innerHTML;

            document.getElementById("toBeEdit").value = uID;
            document.getElementById("taskStatus").value = 'delete';
            //alert("ID: " + uID);
            
            const form  = document.getElementById('editForm');

            form.submit();

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Add a popup before the deleteUser call, use confirm() or custom popup if you need to

Comment: Can you please show me how you will do it? I already tried it but it didn't work. maybe my code was wrong or misplaced.

Comment: Well `if(confirm('Please confirm deletion')) { // delete user }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in method `confirm()` in your `deleteUser()` function. Please see below code,

```
function deleteUser() {
         if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete user?')){
            var rowId = 
                event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
          //this gives id of tr whose button was clicked
            var data = 
            document.getElementById(rowId).querySelectorAll(".row-data"); 
          /*returns array of all elements with 
          "row-data" class within the row with given id*/

            var uID = data[0].innerHTML;

            document.getElementById("toBeEdit").value = uID;
            document.getElementById("taskStatus").value = 'delete';
            //alert("ID: " + uID);
            
            const form  = document.getElementById('editForm');

            form.submit();
          }

        }
```

The `confirm()` method displays a dialog box with a message, an OK button, and a Cancel button.

The `confirm()` method returns true if the user clicked "OK", otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

You should to add this code include your delete function

```
if(window.confirm("do you want delete this data")){
    -->your code with js<--
}else{
    return false;
}
```